# How do I append dynamic HTML after another piece of dynamic HTML is loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have an `<OL>` and a function that reads in json and loads in `<li>`'s. I then have another function that looks at another json and loads the final `<li>`. I want the first function to trigger first and then the second to append the final `<li>` after. However, 1 out of every 10 or so page loads the second function triggers first and the `<li>`s are out of order. BTW the use case is for dynamic breadcrumbs. I am using twitter bootstrap's breadcrumb class to style these elements.

First Trigger:

```
$.getJSON("/requirementdesc/{{ catalog }}/"+ c, function(d) {
 $.each(d, function(k, v) {
  $(".breadcrumb").append("<li><a href='/{{ catalog }}/"+ c +"'>"+ v.raw_requirement_desc +"</a></li>");
 });
});
```

Second Trigger:

```
$.getJSON("/parentrequirement/{{ catalog }}/{{ block }}", function(data) {
 $.each(data, function(key, value) {
  $(".breadcrumb").append("<li class='active'>"+ value.raw_requirement_desc +"</li>");
 });
});
```

I have tried using .promise(), but no luck.

Comment: use `$.when` to load data once both requests are done

Comment: @cale_b How is that comment helpful or constructive in any way? The OP is not asking for anyone to develop anything for them. This is a valid question. Simply ask for their code and move on. There is no need for rude comments.

Comment: Sorry for not adding the code originally!

Comment: @Steve - when the comment was added, there was **zero** code in the question.  It was completely vague, and did not comply with the [SO Documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -  **I acknowledge** I could have been kinder.  This was the nth question today that were vague / without code, and my frustration came through.

Comment: have you tried placing the second function in the first functions callback?

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's [`$.when()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/), which provides a way to execute callback functions based on one or more objects that represent asynchronous events. This code waits for both calls to complete, and then appends the `li`s to the `ol` in order.

```
var li_1,
    li_2;

$.when(
  $.getJSON("/requirementdesc/{{ catalog }}/" + c, function (d) {
    $.each(d, function (k, v) {
      li_1 += "<li><a href='/{{ catalog }}/" + c + "'>" + 
        v.raw_requirement_desc + "</a></li>";
    })
  }),
  $.getJSON("/parentrequirement/{{ catalog }}/{{ block }}", function (data) {
    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
      li_2 += "<li class='active'>" + value.raw_requirement_desc + "</li>";
    })
  })
)
.then(function(){
    if(typeof li_1 === "string" && typeof li_1 !== "undefined") { 
      $(".breadcrumb").append(li_1);
    }
    if(typeof li_2 === "string" && typeof li_2 !== "undefined") { 
      $(".breadcrumb").append(li_2); 
    }
});
```

Note: I didn't test this but it should theoretically work, given your code.

Comment: `1 out of every 10 or so page loads the second function triggers first and the <li>s are out of order` this still doesn't guarantee _first function updates `ol` first_. This code is only making sure that breadcrumbs are updated after both of them have done (regardless of order).

Comment: Updated code to better account for a correct order of the `li`s. Thanks for pointing this out @Ejay.